# Change Setting of printer before print a PDF C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, printing, setting

I want to print a paper with my application with a specific size.
But I don't know how to change it in the setting of the printer.

I have something like that:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.Refresh();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "Name of my Printer";
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.Verb = "Print";
process.StartInfo.FileName = "MyPDF.pdf";
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.Start();
```

But with this code the printer print the paper with the default size and i want to change it.

Thank's for Help!

Comment: Use `PrintDialog` (not the WinForms version).  Using `Process` is not even close.

Comment: Yes but when i try to change the value of data it's say that it's read only and i can't change them.